# How can Wells know what happened in the alternate time?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, arrowverse, the-flash

*I can't be precise hence I have overloaded the question with pics*

As the title asks, when Barry went back to the past in *The Flash*, a series of events happened. One was Cisco discovering that Dr. Wells faked the whole scene with the yellow-suited Flash (see image below)

[image]

and it was actually Dr. Wells who was the man in the yellow suit. In the process of the discovery Cisco got caught and Wells killed Cisco in the process.

[image]

However when the series came back to present time Cisco still had memories, eventually Cisco and Barry came to the conclusion of re-framing the whole scenario so as to get Dr. Wells to confess that he indeed killed Barry's mother so as to be apprehended, but in the recreation of the scene Dr. Wells sent the ShapeShifter [image 5 is the shapeshifter] to represent him (Dr. Wells). The recreation took place however it wasn't Dr. Wells (as you can see his hands are not vibrating). The dialog was exact.

[image]

> My question is, how did Dr.Wells know about something that has not taken place? (The event happened in the past and barry went back to change the fact, hence the future was changed successfully, meaning it did not happen at all.)

To support my question of how Dr. Wells knew about something he didn't, in the final episode of The Flash season 1 Dr. Wells was captured and incarcerated. Cisco approached him about what he said (in the moment that never happened) and he wanted to know how he feels about it. Dr. Wells' reply was that he is clueless of what happened, but if he killed Cisco in the process then he had a good reason, meaning he didn't even know why he killed Cisco. Hence the question.

Comment: I tried to bring a little more structure into the question and its images, including the removal of images that were completely unnecessary for understanding the question.

Comment: oh sir, i am good, don't worry, Thanks for that though.@NapoleonWilson

Comment: That being said, I think it was clarified in the very episode that Wells was recording them on video all the time, so knew everything they talked about.

Comment: rilli? but why then when Cisco asked for a reason as to why he killed him he said  he doesn't know but he had a good reason, but in the dialog of that moment he told Cisco the reason and it was "he was already dead to him in centuries"@NapoleonWilson

Comment: I'm not 100% on your question. Are you asking how Wells could know he had a good reason? Or how Wells knew about the trap? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cde mentions in his answer, Wells did have cameras all over the place (the Cortex, Barry's lab, Iris' desk at work, the West/Allen house and numerous other places), but that doesn't fully answer your question, as he obviously couldn't see events on there that never happened (or rather that were changed).

cde also correctly mentions that the Speed Force protects speedsters from changes in the timeline - to a degree at least - but as you point out in your question, Eobard was genuinely surprised when Cisco reported he (ET) killed him (CR).

So, while Eobard had Barry's lab bugged (which is where they brought the body of the real Harrison Wells and did Cisco's trip down alternate memory lane, after all), he knew they were onto him.

---

Now it gets a bit complicated (which means I have to go a bit of a long way to get to my point):

Eobard was aware of that much earlier then strictly makes sense (IMO), because Joe told Cisco about his suspicion about Wells in Barry's lab, yet Eobard did nothing to prevent them finding out anything more, probably because he thought it would accomplish two things:

- divert suspicion from him, since only Eobard's DNA and not Well's
  could be found and
- it would get the idea of time travel into Barry, pushing him to go
  faster, with the possible goal in mind of saving his mom, and Eobard
  needs Barry to reach that speed in order to get back home.

Barry told Joe he believed Joe's theory, also in the lab, and when they decided to go to Starling City they did so in the West/Allen living room, yet here again Eobard did nothing to move Well's body or mask his tracks. He did however move up his timetable a bit, since everything (Grodd, Everyman, the rebuild particle accelerator) was falling into place and he probably believed Barry being able to be fast enough by then.

---

Having done this rather extensive detour I can finally coming round to answering what you're specifically asking, just after mentioning the rather important fact that they also did Cisco's "dream walk" in Barry's lab, so the
important points (vibrating hand through heart, calling Cisco a son, confessing Nora's murder, but stating that that had not been the intention)

How then **did** *Everyman* know what to say? How could it match almost verbatim with what was said in the alternate timeline?

**Eobard told him what to say, simple as that.** Like the hologram of Reverse Flash, *Every"wells"* said, what Eobard would have said, had he actually been there. The alternate timeline Eobard did speak from the heart and told Cisco what he truely felt, which is after all what the real Eobard felt (changing one day didn't alter that significantly enough), so he was able to give *Everyman* an accurate enough "script" to follow ("Nora wasn't the intended target", "Cisco is like a son", walking up menacing with hand outstretched).

Answer (score 5):

Wells has had cameras in every location of note. He was monitoring what the scoobies were planning. And Cisco's very vivid lucid dreaming included all the details he needed to know in order to have Everyman recreate the scene close enough to scare Cisco who only half remembered it.

Additionally,  in both comics and the show, Eobard, like most speed force speedster are somewhat immune to time changes, similar to how Cisco was portrayed. Flashpoint Paradox is a prime example. Zoom who was not involved in Barry's saving his mom, had no memory loss from the alternative time line.

finally, Gideon, the advanced A.I. is able to track changes in the timeline. This can help Wells fill in any holes from what he learned from Cisco's recorded dream.